# Showing listbox items into table onClick using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, listbox

I am very new to jQuery. I have a listbox with selected items in it from other listbox. I want to show the all selected items in table rows one below the other on Button Click..

Till now I have done something like this..But the code is not running(***sel1*** is listbox1, **sel2** is listbox2, **tab2** is table id).

In the code below I want to show sel2 items in first column of the table..

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
    for(i=1;i<$(#'sel2').length;i++)
        {
      $("#tab2 tbody").append("<tr><td></td>'(#sel2).val'<td><input type='text'></td></tr>")
        }});
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello plz try this one and i hope this will help you solve the current problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<select id="sel2" multiple>
    <option value="first">first option</option>
    <option value="second">sec option</option>
    <option value="third">third option</option>
    <option value="fourth">fourth option</option>
    <option value="fifth">fifth option</option>
    <option value="sixth">six option</option>
</select>


<table id="tab2">
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<button id="add" value="Add">Add</button>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function()
 {

    $("#add").click(function()
    {
        var selectval = $('#sel2').val();

        var len = selectval.length;

        for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
            $("#tab2 tbody").append("<tr><td>"+selectval[i]+"</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>");
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @syed..But i want to show all sel2's items in first column of table on single click.According to ur solution each time i have to select the item from select n click add button.My both '<select>' are of **multiple selection** so for that i have tried '$("#sel2").lenght' but its bot working..

Comment: @syed..Thanks.. it helped me a bit..but still need some more finishing in 'sel2' i m having selected items from 'sel1'..now i just want to display all item names n texboxes on button ckick...from ur solution i have to select all items from 'sel2' n its not showing the names of the selected items..pls help

Comment: and one more i want to retreive the tab2's both columns value to insert into database...how it can be retrived?

Comment: @Atit plz can you update your question with full code. I hope after that you can solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: if this answer really help you or something like that you should accept the answer. Otherwise make question little bit clear with update your question code.

Comment: insert into database this is another issue and i saw you already post another question (with my answer code) related database. Thanks @Atit